# How do I change the GRUB default boot?

Tags: grub

I'm trying to configure grub on my computer. I use the dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu. The grub always suggest with a countdown from 10 seconds to boot the Ubuntu. However, I do not want to be that way because other people in my home also use the computer and do not have much affinity with Linux. I wonder if there is a way to set Windows as the main option.

I found these commands but I could not move much:

```
~$ grub-
grub-bios-setup       grub-mkconfig         grub-mkstandalone
grub-editenv          grub-mkdevicemap      grub-mount
grub-file             grub-mkfont           grub-ntldr-img
grub-fstest           grub-mkimage          grub-probe
grub-glue-efi         grub-mklayout         grub-reboot
grub-install          grub-mknetdir         grub-render-label
grub-kbdcomp          grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2  grub-script-check
grub-macbless         grub-mkrelpath        grub-set-default
grub-menulst2cfg      grub-mkrescue         grub-syslinux2cfg
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this is straightforward.  Boot Linux, open a command prompt and type:

```
$ (your favorite text editor) /etc/default/grub
$ sudo grub-mkconfig
```

The content of the default grub configuration on my system is:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Fedora"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.md=0 rd.dm=0  KEYTABLE=us quiet SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb rd.luks=0 rd.lvm.lv=vg_lenovor61/lv_root LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd.lvm.lv=vg_lenovor61/lv_swap"
```

The timeout is easily changed.  Making Windows the default is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader).

In my Fedora distribution, grub is named `grub2` everywhere, but the semantics of this part is the same.

Comment: For ubuntu you'd better use `sudo update-grub` instead of manually running `grub-mkconfig`

Answer (score 1):

```
grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg # it will show all available menuentries
nano /etc/default/grub # replace GRUB_DEFAULT=0 with GRUB_DEFAULT="needed menu entry from above"
update-grub # update grub configuration file
```

[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)